# Heisenbug issue with using a dll. What do I do next?

Tags: c++, dll

I am working on a system that uses a Voltage Controlled Oscillator chip (VCO) to help process a signal.  The makers of the chip (Analog Devices) provide a program to load setup files onto the VCO but I want to be able to setup the chip from within the overarching signal processing control system.  Fortunately Analog Devices also provides a DLL to interface with their chip and load setup files myself.  I am programming in Visual C++ 6.0 (old I know) and my program is a dialog application.

I got the system to work perfectly writing setup files to the card and reading its status.  I then decided that I needed to handle the case where there are multiple cards attached and one must be selected.  The DLL provides GetDeviceCount() which returns an integer.  For some reason every time the executable runs it returns 15663105 (garbage I assume).  Whenever I debug my code however the function returns the correct number of cards.  Here is my call to GetDeviceCount().

```
typedef int (__stdcall *GetDeviceCount)();

int AD9516_Setup()
{
    int NumDevices;
    GetDeviceCount _GetDeviceCount;
    HINSTANCE hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary("AD9516Interface.dll");
    _GetDeviceCount = (GetDeviceCount)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary,"GetDeviceCount");
    NumDevices = _GetDeviceCount();
    return NumDevices;
}
```

Just to be clear: every other function from the DLL I have used is called exactly like this and works perfectly in the executable and debugger.  I did some research and found out that a common cause of Heisenbugs is threading.  I know that there is some threading behind the scenes in the dialogs I am using so I deleted all my calls to the function except one.  I also discovered that the debugger code executes slower than executable code and I thought the chip may not have enough time to finish processing each command.  First I tried taking up time between each chip function call by inserting an empty for loop and when that did not work I commented out all other calls to the DLL.

I do not have access to the source code used to build the DLL and I have no idea why its function would be returning garbage in the executable and not debugger.  What other differences are there between running in debugger and executing that could cause an error?  What are some other things I can do to search for this error?

Comment: Everything always runs a bit slower in the debugger, because for debugging to work there has to be extra stuff in the compiled code.  So that's expected.  Can you post exactly where your garbage is being returned from?  Given that it's always the same, I would doubt it's uninitialized garbage, but you could confirm this by running it on a different computer if you can.

Comment: I don't know if it's garbage or not, but 15663105 converts to 0xef0001, which looks like a count in the low byte (or 2) and maybe a status in the upper byte. I'd go checkout the docs on the device and see what types of status codes it returns.

Comment: Are you sure the correct declaration for the function return value is `int` and not for example `short`?

Comment: Have your tried starting the application normally and then only later attaching a debugger to see if the problem also occurs then? In debug builds you're using a special heap and memory functions that clear memory areas to special values, that might change something provided you're accidentally using uninitialized memory.

Comment: The garbage comes from NumDevices = _GetDeviceCount();  I don't know any way of finding out what is going on inside that function.  Running it on a different computer would be very difficult because the software interfaces with custom hardware installed in this computer.  I would be willing to try and set it up but I definitely want to try any other options first.

Comment: I didn't know attaching a debugger later was possible. I will try that and get back to you.  The declaration is definitely int.  The documentation on the card is not very extensive, according to it, it should only ever return the integer number of cards.  I will see if i can find better documentation somewhere.

Comment: @Hammer - to be clear, does the documentation explicitly say to use `int`, or does it just say integer?  Also, what's a common number it might be returning in debug mode?

Comment: You're not validating that LoadLibrary() is succeeding. You really need to test for failure and report it. It may be the load is failing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Mr.Jefferson, you are completely right.  The documentation said integer and not int.  I changed the type to short (like you said @6502) and it worked perfectly.  Thank you SO MUCH!

Comment: @Hammer - this makes sense given other comments that debug builds will zero out variables for you.  As Peter Rowell pointed out above, your "garbage" translates into a convenient-looking binary string.  I bet your assignment was always just setting the lower half of the 32-bit integer.  The fact that the upper half of your `int` was always the same "garbage" still seems a bit weird, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some compilers/IDEs add extra padding to variables in debug builds or initialize them to 0 - this might explain the differences you're encountering between debugging and "normal" execution.

Some things that might be worth checking:
- are you using the correct calling convention?
- do you get the same return value if no devices are connected?
- are you using the correct return type (uint vs int vs long vs ..)?

Comment: I tried disconnecting the device (normally there is 1 card) and the return value went down by 1.  That was suspicious so i went back and double checked the return type and it was a 16 bit integer not an int.  I changed the return type to short and it works fine now :)  A few people suggested the return type early on in the comments but i was sure it was correct.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `_GetDeviceCount` to 0 before calling the function; that could be what the debugger is doing for you.

Comment: When i do that i just get a runtime error.  _GetDeviceCount is a pointer to the function in the library so setting it to 0 then makes calling it throw an error.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Oh!  No, then set NumDevices to 0 before assigning it.